# Длина int в CUDA

Tags: c++, c, cuda

Вопрос в том как в CUDA с/с++ создать int переменную длиной 64bit ? Желательно unsigned.
Будет ли длина зависеть от видеокарты или от компилятора?

```
 long int i;

 i= 10;

 printf(" Size = %d byte\n", sizeof(i));
```

такая конструкция дает 4, а мне для задачи нужно 8 байт

Comment: попробуйте _int64 (это тип переменной)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__int64` или `long long int` и, соответственно, `unsigned __int64` или `unsigned long long int`